# rsync per-site configuration file?

Tags: linux, ssh, android, rsync

I know how to configure a per-site entry for ssh, but is there any kind of a client configuration for rsync that allows per-site configuration options and aliases or similar shortcuts like the .ssh/config?

I'm curious because I have a minimal ssh server installed on my android phone and I also have a minimal rsync tool on it as well. I'm getting tired of having to root login onto the phone and sym-link both tools to standard places the android OS looks for executables as the ssh server is bare bones and has a typical *bear multi-link binary for the basic unix commands (that does not include rsync)

I end up having to include --rsync-path=/path/to/rsync/android/files/rsync every time I want to do any rsyncing of the files on my phone, but this path is always the same. I've gotten around it in the meantime with a glob approach in a shell script wrapper, but this sometimes limits the customization I can do with the rsync call.

I'm just wondering if there is anything similar to the .ssh/config file where I can create an alias for my phone (e.g. 'android') where specifying rsync android:/mnt/sdcard will automatically assume --rsync-path=/blah/blah/blah --no-g --no-p --no-t etc.

Tre`

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ssh forced-commands`. It's easy to use and it forces the target host to run a certain command. The gist is:

1. Create a new key pair.
2. Put the public key in the android user's authorized_keys file, with the following at the beginning of the line: `command="/path/to/rsync $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
3. Add this argument to the rsync command `-e "/path/to/ssh -i /path/to/private_key"

This will force the android to run the indicated program, the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND parameter will be replaced by any other options. Google "rsync forced-command" and you'll find plenty of recipes.